# Strong induction: Question about formatting inductive step

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

As an example, say I am proving a proposition P(n) for natural numbers $n \geq 0$. In my base case, assume I've proved P(0), P(1), P(2).

In my inductive step, do I assume the claim holds for $i=0,1,2,...n-1$ and show the claim holds for $n$, OR do I assume the claim holds for $i=3,4,...n-1$ (i.e. assume the claim holds for values $i >$ than those used in the base cases) and show it holds for $n$?

Answer (score 1):

In *strong* induction you assume it holds for *all* numbers smaller than $n$ ... Why? Well, that's just how strong induction is defined.  Note that technically, you don't even have to prove a separate base case for strong induction: as long as you can prove that $n$ has property $P$ assuming all natural numbers smaller than $n$ have property $n$, then you'll have proven that all natural numbers have property $n$. In practice, though, you often end up having to prove the base case separate anyway, for with $n=0$, proving that $\forall k (k < n \rightarrow P(k)( \rightarrow P(0)$ amounts to proving $P(0)$, since the antecedent of this conditional is vacuously true.

OK, but I think your question really was: 'Do I *have to* assume all those cases when doing induction in general? That is, can I do an inductive proof *without* assuming all those cases?'. And here the answer is: If you can prove the $n$ case without assuming all of the cases, then that's just fine.

In fact, this is *exactly* what's done in (typical) *weak* induction: you merely assume it holds true for $n-1$. If that is enough to show it holds for $n$, then that's sufficient for the step, and it will complete the inductive proof. Please note though that the $n-1$ term may reach back into the base case for small $n$, e.g in your case you will be including $2$ after all when $n=3$.

Finally, there are forms of weak induction where you need to reach back further, e.g where you need to assume the inductive hypothesis for $n-2$ in addition to $n-1$.  Such cases are sometimes called 'strong weak induction'. However, you would still not need to assume the inductive hypothesis to be true for *all* of the natural numbers in order for this to work.

Comment: When you say there are forms of weak induction where you need to reach back further, do you mean that you also need to assume for $n-2$ and so on (not all the way down to $0$)?

Comment: @Natash1 Right.  For example, suppose you want to use induction prove something about the Fibonacci numbers ... then most likely you 'll want to assume that the claim holds true for $n-2$ and $n-1$ in order to show it holds true for $n$.

Comment: Cool so it's basically strong induction except we really only need $n-2$ and $n-1$ for that sequence?

Comment: @Natash1 When there is a fixed number that you reach back, it's typically seen as a form of weak induction, rather than strong induction. Reaching back $2$ or more is sometimes called 'strong weak induction'.